# C# Word Document, replace selected Range text?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I was trying to do a find and replace in a word document, but because the text to find is over 255 characters, so it will run into error using the below method:

```
app.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
                ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
```

I found someone have a solution which can manage to return the range which contains the long text in Word document, so I am trying to replace the text of this range and save the changes. But I couldn't figure out how to do the replacement after trying something like:
Get the selected range containing long text

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range selectedRange = findTextRange(app, findText);
```

Try to replace the value of returned selectedRange with:

```
app.Selection.Range.Text = replaceWithText;
```

It doesn't have any problem to execute, but the saved document doesn't have the change. So I am not sure what I missed?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `findTextRange` doesn't select the range for you?

> ```
> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range selectedRange = findTextRange(app, findText);
> app.Selection.Range.Text = replaceWithText;
> ```

Replace the 2nd line with:

```
selectedRange.Text = replaceWithText; // and, you might want to rename `selectedRange`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do using ASPOSE file formate API for this problem.This should be easy rather than another solution i think.Add this reference to your nuget of visual studio.

```
string dataDir = RunExamples.GetDataDir_FindAndReplace();
string fileName = "TestFile.doc";

Document doc = new Document(dataDir + fileName);

FindReplaceOptions options = new FindReplaceOptions();
options.ReplacingCallback = new ReplaceEvaluatorFindAndHighlight();
options.Direction = FindReplaceDirection.Backward;
```

// We want the "your document" phrase to be highlighted.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("your document", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
doc.Range.Replace(regex, "", options);

dataDir = dataDir + RunExamples.GetOutputFilePath(fileName);
```

// Save the output document.

```
doc.Save(dataDir);
```

Please follow the below link:
https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/Find+and+Replace